# Prevent Duplicate Report Submit into Database - PHP

Tags: php, duplicates

I am checking to see if a fellowship date has already been submitted in the mysql db. I want to prevent the user from submitting a report with the same fellowship date.

**Here is my code:**

```
$datecheck = mysql_query("SELECT 'fellowship_date' FROM pcc_report WHERE 'fellowship_date' = '$_POST[fellowship_date]'");

$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($datecheck);

if('$_POST['fellowship_date]' == $result['fellowship_date'])
{
  showAlert("Duplicate Entry");
return;
}
```

But when I click SUBMIT in the form, it submits it anyway and ignores my script thereby inserting several duplicates in my server.

Please help!

Comment: typo? `if('$_POST['fellowship_date]'` should be `if($_POST['fellowship_date']`

Comment: put the date on db as unique field?

Answer (score 0):

`if('$_POST['fellowship_date]' == $result['fellowship_date'])`

to

`if($_POST['fellowship_date'] == $result['fellowship_date'])`

(remove single quotes, and propperly close `fellowship_date`)